# Found expired check issued by title company to settle balance from 6 years ago

Tags: united-states, check, expiration, oregon

I purchased a home 6 years ago and the title company sent me a large packet of documents related to closing with a small check buried deep inside it.  I did not notice the check until now.  It's only $38, but I'd still like to deposit it.  The check says void after 90 days which have long passed.  Should I just deposit the check and see what happens?  Is there a statute of limitations where the company could say, "Oh, too much time has passed, we no longer owe you the balance."  What should I do?

Edit: State is Oregon (Washington County)

Answer (score 5):

The laws on unclaimed funds vary from state to state and country to country. The check is likely expired. In the U.S. most banks will not cash one older than six months. You have a couple options:

1. Search your state's "unclaimed property or funds" database -- a Google search of that search term with your state should give you the appropriate official web site. Depending on the type of unclaimed fund and your state's laws, you might have up to seven years (give or take) to claim the funds, so you might have luck there. For amounts under $50, the reporting rules are often less strict, so it may not have been reported.
2. Contact the Title company and ask if they can reissue or if they have any other guidance.

Comment: I checked the state's unclaimed property database and I do not see any entry for my name.  If I contact the title company and ask for a new check, can they legally say no?  Do I still have a legal right to that balance which was owed to me?